# Angular extend API model for component purpose

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I often have needs to extend my API model with parameters I use just in component view.

For Example I have a model:

```
export class Person {
  name: string;
  surname: string;
  address: string;
}
```

It is something I get from API:

```
getPersons(): Observable<Person[]> {
  return this.httpClient.get<Person[]>`${environment.API}/person`);
}
```

When I get this in my component I often need to extend model with parameter/attribute I get in data processing after request or just simple 'active'/'select' parameter for UI visualization tracking.

Which approach to use for this purpose. I know for 2 solutions:

1) Add parameter to the class model even if that parameter do not participate in server response, just separate them from standard parameters:

```
export class Person {
  name: string;
  surname: string;
  address: string;

  ui_active: boolean;   // I know that those parameters are not from API        
  ui_fullName: string;  // response but they are here to make my life easier
}
```

2) Make another extend class with those parameters:

```
export class PersonExtended extends Person  {
  ui_active: boolean;       
  ui_fullName: string
}
```

But this approach complicate thing since I have 2 models, and I need to switch between to them all the time.

What is the best practice for this kind of situation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make those fields optional with the `?`-operator:

```
export class Person {
  name: string;
  surname: string;
  address: string;

  ui_active?: boolean;       
  ui_fullName?: string; 
}
```

Thus, you can use them but you don't have to.

EDIT:

If you have to remove them somewhen use the following generic method:

```
private omitFields<T>(object: T, fields: Array<string>): T {
    for (let field of fields) {
        delete object[field];
    }
    return object;
}
```

And use it, for example, like this:

```
this.omitFields(el, ['ui_active', 'ui_fullName']);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I like this approach much more, but I was doubt in it since I have heard many times that is not best practice.

Comment: I updated my answer. I added a generic method you can use to remove optional fields if needed, for example if you have to resend this objects to the backend.

Comment: Maybe we can also add one method for example 'getOriginalAPIObject' to the every class extended with this kind of fields, which can return object without those optional parameter. In that case I do not need to send array of properties I want to escape, every class will take a care of its own optional parameters ?

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but then you have to map the already contained objects to the base object.

Answer (score 2):

I think codewise second option is right, but as far as I know there is nothing wrong with the first option, just make sure the new parameters can be null or ignored some way so you dont get errors if you dont set them where they are not needed.